# What is the Regex ? every unicode characters (but not every blank ones except the spaces)

Tags: regex

I am basically trying to find a Regex against which you could test a Nickname/Pseudo after a form validation.

For exemple I want this to be allowed:
`"ཀུ༇ༀ"`
or this
`0X-_my perfect name_-X0"`
but not this
`"my\tperfectname"`

so no \n \t \r etc... while still keeping spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the pattern:

```
[^\n\r\t]+
```

Or if you wanna be more thorough:

```
[^\n\r\t\f\v]+
```

Comment: mm doesn't seem to work : the \r is not interpreted and "eeeeeer" doesn't pass

Comment: @nepriel What regex implementation are you using?

Comment: @nepriel try it with: `^[^\n\r\t\f\v]+$`